# Download a file in Dropbox using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using ASP.net MVC 4 and Dropbox API to download a file from my Dropbox account. I've successfully installed the api in my project and I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial) to understand the functionalities but I'm getting an error if I run:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
> Parameter name: path

Here is my code:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> DropDls()
    {
        var dbx = new DropboxClient("MY-TOKEN");
        string folder = "My Folder";
        string file = "My File.rar";

        using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(folder + "/" + file))
        {
            await response.GetContentAsStringAsync();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I'm a beginner to API related work, so can't figure it out what is wrong in here. What can I try next?

Comment: Did you exchange MY-TOKEN with your actual token or is this just for the sake of the question?

Comment: ofcourse I did! This is just for the security reasons.

Comment: Just checking. It seems your file is not found. Execute a ListFolderAsync which will give you all the files/folders in the directory and download based on that

Comment: I tried that in another console app project, but nothing comes up. How can I do that in my MVC project and show the result in view?

Answer (score 1):

Non-root paths for the Dropbox API should start with "/". Your code is:

```
    string folder = "My Folder";
    string file = "My File.rar";
```

...

```
    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync(folder + "/" + file))
```

That will result in a path "My Folder/My File.rar", but it should actually be "/My Folder/My File.rar". So, instead, you probably want code like this instead:

```
    using (var response = await dbx.Files.DownloadAsync("/" + folder + "/" + file))
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get a error of `path/not_found/.`.

Comment: That indicates that the supplied path doesn't correspond to anything in the account. Make sure your path is correct, e.g., in this example, "/My Folder/My File.rar". You can use [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesRoutes_ListFolderAsync.htm) to list a folder.